# Creating a Multi-Contact Event with Apex

Tags: apex

I am attempting to use Apex to create a multi-contact event.

I have already enabled `Allow Users to Relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks and Events` in the activity settings in the scratch org.

I am following the guide and the example at the bottom of [these](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_event.htm) docs but I am constantly getting an error when pushing to the scratch org:

```
// ...
event.setEventWhoIds(attendeeContactIds);
// ...
```

`Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void setEventWhoIds(List<String>) from the type Event`.

I also tried to write directly to the field with:

```
event.EventWhoIds = attendeeContactIds;
```

With that, I get the error, that the field is not writable.

`attendeeContactIds` is a List of Strings representing Contact IDs.

What could I be missing? ‍♂️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the shared events feature, but based on what I've read so far it seems that the `setEventWhoIds()` method is only provided through the SOAP API (i.e. it's not available if you're using Apex directly in Salesforce).

The SOAP API documentation can be handy for figuring out things like if you should be able to query an object or perform CRUD on it, which fields you can generally expect, and whether those fields can be written to. I wouldn't generally expect samples found in the SOAP API documentation to work in Apex though.

In Apex, you'll have to do things the long way. That is...

- Create your `Event` record, and insert it
- Iterate over your prospective list of attendees
- Create an `EventRelation` record for each of them, setting the appropriate fields (looks like `EventId` and `RelationId` are the important ones here)
- Insert the `EventRelation` records (outside of the loop, of course)